# How can I break up an XMLDocument into smaller parts for processing with XPath in Swift?

Tags: swift, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have an XML document that I would like to be able to parse using the  `XMLDocument` DOM parser.  I know I can use XPath to parse the pieces I'm interested in from the Document. However I'd prefer to be able to parse out certain elements with an XPath and treat those elements as a document by itself.  Here's a trivial example to clarify.

```
import Foundation

class XMLDocumentExample {
    let xml = """
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Report xmlns="urn:com.conorgriffin/support/Report">
        <name>SpreadsheetGeneration</name>
        <reference-id>98ecd186d83301b418add9fb2006937f</reference-id>
        <common-id>F5S|242C11A2|5F9B870E</common-id>
        <customer>customer1</customer>
        <job-integration>
            <integration>load-data</integration>
            <id>675573850</id>
        </job-integration>
        <job-integration>
            <integration>generate-spreadsheet</integration>
            <id>136683540</id>
        </job-integration>
    </Report>
    """

    func parse() {
        do {
            let doc = try XMLDocument.init(xmlString: xml, options: [])
            let name = try doc.nodes(forXPath: "/Report/name")[0].stringValue
            let referenceID = try doc.nodes(forXPath: "/Report/reference-id")[0].stringValue
            let commonID = try doc.nodes(forXPath: "/Report/common-id")[0].stringValue
            let customer = try doc.nodes(forXPath: "/Report/customer")[0].stringValue
            let jobs = try doc.nodes(forXPath: "/Report/job-integration")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

So now I have some strings extracted from the child nodes of the top element `Report`, I also have an array of `XMLNode` in variable `jobs`.  I'd like to pass this `jobs` variable to another function and use XPath to get the inner details of each job.  I do not want to have to include the `Report` element in the XPaths e.g. `"/Report/job-integration/integration"`.

How can I treat each `job-integration` node as a document in its own right so I can parse it with XPaths that are relative to the `job-integration` element such as `"/integration"` or `"/id"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, it turns out I was almost there but was not using XPath correctly.

Once I passed a `job-integration` node from my initial code above into the function below I could use the `.` character at the beginning of the XPath query to indicate I wanted a result relative to the current node.

```
func build(node: XMLNode) -> JobIntegration {
        do {
            let integrationName = try node.nodes(forXPath: "./integration/text()")[0]
            let integrationId = try node.nodes(forXPath: "./id/text()")[0]
            return JobIntegration(id: integrationId, integration: integrationName)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```